# Checking validity of Geodatabase file using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, file-geodatabase, validation

As the title suggests, how can I whether a GDB file is valid using ArcPy? One approach is, only checking the whether the name ends with `.gdb`, but that's not a robust approach. Because a normal file can be ended with `.gdb`, where GDBs are essentially folders to OS. So how can I do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Where @Get Spatial's answer is partially correct, but it doesn't solve the problem directly. So answering my own question:

```
desc = arcpy.Describe(filePath)
print desc.dataType
```

It prints the type of the object given path is directing. For folders, it prints `Folder` and for geodatabases it prints `Workspace`

Answer (score 9):

The following code is used to [List Workspaces](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000v0000001w000000), in this case, File Geodatabases.  It does not check for the file extension `.gdb`, but is looking for its internal type.  This should leave out directories with a `.gdb` extension, but which are not actually File GDB's.

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/Data" 

# List all file geodatabases in the current workspace 
# 
workspaces = arcpy.ListWorkspaces("*", "FileGDB")
for workspace in workspaces: 
    # Print workspace name
    #
    print workspace
```